# cant do partial upgrade

Tags: partial-upgrade

```
Your system does not contain a ubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-desktop, xubuntu-core, xubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop, mythbuntu-desktop, kubuntu-netbook, lubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-gnome-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntukylin-desktop or ubuntu-budgie-desktop package and it was not possible to detect which version of Ubuntu you are running.
 Please install one of the packages above first using synaptic or apt-get before proceeding.
```

running ubuntu 18.10 64bit

Comment: What command were you trying to perform?  `do-release-upgrade` does not require a desktop to be added in order to perform an upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04, so what you were you using?  See the *Upgrading from 18.10* section in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes  if this is what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first install `ubuntu-desktop` by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Then, please reboot your system and try to update again by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: ok im trying that now

Comment: @Pro I'll wait for you, in case you need help. Best of luck

Comment: give me a while i have like 5 kbps internet connection

Comment: i'll update you tommorrow

Comment: @Pro I'll be waiting. Best of luck